# MySQL Node JS DELETE no working - 0 rows affected

Tags: mysql, node.js, delete-row

I am trying to create a post route that will delete a user's data from several tables. I checked in mySQL workbench that the database user has this privilege. However when I click delete on the frontend, the queries appear to run but the rows do not get deleted. Can you someone please tell me where I am going wrong?

```
app.post('/disposal', redirectLogin, async(req, res) => {
      const user = res.locals;
      userStmt = `DELETE FROM users WHERE user_name ='${user.user_name}'`;
      cashStmt = `DELETE FROM CASH WHERE user_name ='${user.user_name}'`;
      tradesStmt = `DELETE FROM trades WHERE user_name ='${user.user_name}'`;
      holdingsStmt = `DELETE FROM trades WHERE user_name ='${user.user_name}'`;
      await connection.query(userStmt, (err, results) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(results);
        connection.query(holdingsStmt, (err, results) => {
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log(results);
          connection.query(cashStmt, (err, results) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(results);
          });
          connection.query(tradesStmt, (err, results) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(results);
          });
        });
      });
      req.session.destroy(err => {
        if (err) {
          return res.redirect("/dashboard");
        }
        res.clearCookie(SESS_NAME);
        res.send("Ninja disposed!");
      })
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to nest the calls if you are using `async/await`.
As the `res.locals` is an object which contains the `user` property, you have to get the user property.

You could get it by using `Object destructuring` syntax.

Try this.

```
app.post('/disposal', redirectLogin, async (req, res) => {
    const { user } = res.locals;
    userStmt = `DELETE FROM users WHERE user_name ='${user.user_name}'`;
    cashStmt = `DELETE FROM CASH WHERE user_name ='${user.user_name}'`;
    tradesStmt = `DELETE FROM trades WHERE user_name ='${user.user_name}'`;
    holdingsStmt = `DELETE FROM trades WHERE user_name ='${user.user_name}'`;
    try {
        let results = await connection.query(userStmt);
        console.log(results);
        let holdinResult = await connection.query(holdingsStmt);
        console.log(holdinResult);
        let cashResult = await connection.query(cashStmt);
        console.log(cashResult);
        let tradesResult = await connection.query(tradesStmt);
        console.log(tradesResult);
    } catch (error) {
        throw error
    }
    req.session.destroy(err => {
        if (err) {
            return res.redirect("/dashboard");
        }
        res.clearCookie(SESS_NAME);
        res.send("Ninja disposed!");
    })
})
```

Comment: Alright tried that at first and it still ran with no errors but the log showed me as user_name = undefined. So I changed user = res.locals to {user} = res.locals so that it can be extracted properly. Now it works.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to change user = res.locals to { user } = res.locals as it the former was coming back 'undefined' as it was not properly extracting.